# How generate random number in range -10 to 10

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

Hello I am developing one game in which object has to move around the screen on random position. i am using cocos2dx framework. my code is

```
CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    int minY = HelloWorld::bird->getContentSize().height/2;
    int maxY = winSize.height - HelloWorld::bird->getContentSize().height/2;
    int minX = HelloWorld::bird->getContentSize().width/2;
    int maxX = winSize.width - HelloWorld::bird->getContentSize().width/2;
    int range = maxX - minX;
    int actualY = (rand() % range) + minY;
    int actualX = (rand() % range) + minX;
    //HelloWorld::bird->setPosition(ccp(actualX, actualY));
    CCActionInterval*  actionTo = CCMoveTo::actionWithDuration(3, ccp(actualX,actualY));
    HelloWorld::runAction(actionTo);
```

it is working But generating only positive number. so sprite is going out of screen. i searched for tutorial but did not get.

Comment: try searching SO.................

Answer (score 8):

`CCRANDOM_MINUS1_1() * 10.0f` if you are using cocos2d-x

my answer never get accepted even it suits the asker best.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
int min = -10;

int max = 10;

Random r = new Random();

int i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
```

**Note that nextInt(int max) returns an int between 0 inclusive and max exclusive. Ence the +1.**

Comment: run the code in a loop. sometimes i1 will have the value of max.

Comment: what header do I have to include to access Random?

Answer (score 0):

Use `random(T min, T max)`

```
int randomNo = random(-10, 10);
```

It generates random no in range of -10 and 10.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
int result = r.nextInt(max - min) + min;
instead of 
int result = r.nextInt(max) + min;
```

as nextInt takes the range of the random numbers rather than the actual upper limit.

Answer (score -1):

```
boolean cof1=rand.nextBoolean();

if (!cof1)
    result =-result ;
```